# Storybook re-renders story after receiving MSW response

Tags: reactjs, storybook, webpack-hmr, msw, storybook-addon

When I trigger requests to the backend within a Storybook story, the story is re-rendered after receiving the response from Mock Service Worker (MSW). How can I prevent the re-rendering from happening?

Here's the story:

I followed the tutorial on https://storybook.js.org/addons/msw-storybook-addon to set up MSW for my Storybook stories.

So I:

1. installed `msw` and `msw-storybook-addon`
2. generated a service worker: `npx msw init static/`
3. updated my `preview.js` to call the `initialize()` function, added the `mswDecorator`, and set some global handlers (e. g. for `"/api/customers"`)

When opening a component in Storybook that includes a request to `"/api/customers"` the following happens:

1. Initially MSW is telling me that it's enabled: **[MSW] Mocking enabled.**
2. I click a button to manually send a request to `"/api/customers"`
3. MSW is telling me that this API request is covered: **[MSW] 15:21:20 GET /api/customers/ (200 OK)**
4. I print the request results on the console - that works and I can see the expected results printed
5. But right after that the story is unintentionally re-rendered - this is what I want to suppress.

FF is telling me:

> The connection to http://localhost:6006/__webpack_hmr was interrupted
> while the page was loading.

Chrome doesn't give me that piece of information.

Here's the setup:

**package.json:**

```
{
    ...
    "msw": {
        "workerDirectory": "static"
    }
}
```

**main.js (Storybook):**

```
// imports ...    
const toPath = (filePath) => path.join(process.cwd(), filePath);

module.exports = {
  core: {
    builder: "webpack5",
  },
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
  ],
  features: {
    emotionAlias: false,
  },
  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      module: {
        ...config.module,
        rules: custom.module.rules, // rules how to handle file extensions
      },
      resolve: {
        ...config.resolve,
        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
          "@emotion/core": toPath("node_modules/@emotion/react"),
          "emotion-theming": toPath("node_modules/@emotion/react"),
        },
      },
    };
  },
  staticDirs: ["../path/to/static/"], // that's our public
};
```

Here's some code:

**preview.js**

```
export const parameters =  {
    ...
    msw: {
      handlers: [
        rest.get("/api/customers", (req, res, ctx) => {
          let customers = ...;
        
          return res(
            ctx.json({
              data: customers,
            })
          );
        }),
      ],
    },
  }
```

**ExampleStory.stories.jsx:**

```
export default {
  title: "Customers",
};

const getCustomers = () => {
    // ... set axios config etc.
    axios.get("/api/customers", config)
        .then((response) => response.data.data)
        .then((customers) => console.log(customers)); // yep, the customers gets printed!
};

export const ExampleStory = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Simple demo story
      <button onClick={getCustomers}>Get customers</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Node Modules:**

- Storybook@6.5.9
- msw@0.42.3
- msw-storybook-addon@1.6.3

Comment: Any chance your story depends on the data you're fetching or updates the internal state once the response is received? If that's the case, then the story will re-render per React component lifecycle. If that's not the case, try profiling your story to know why it re-renders (there are npm packages in the wild to help you with that).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @kettanaito! Well, the story is supposed to display content that is being loaded. Therefore, there needs to be a rerendering of the story.
But interestingly, the whole iframe is reloaded, not just the story.